# TeamCity 'Missing unknown' Git error

Tags: git, teamcity

Our nightly build failed last night with the following:

```
Failed to build patch for build #400 {build id=1296, buildTypeId=AllinOneGo_DevServer}, VCS root: "repolocation" {instance id=68, parent internal id=3, parent id=build name, description: "repolocation"}, due to error: 'build patch' command failed. stderr: Missing unknown d87f32e4ffba6c58690c3490559880cbb0e2a95b
```

If I run `git show d87f32` it drops down into vim on some Microsoft XML config file I don't recognize. I can't find this file in the repo.

We have encountered this error before and it 'magically' fixed itself. No changes that we put in, just tried to build a few days later and it worked. Any ideas?

Cloning/pushing/pulling to the repo works fine just using Git Bash.

Comment: I tracked down the file to which the hash refers. It is an Entity Framework generated resx file that has been in the repo for years.

Git fsck mentions some dangling blobs but that is it.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the server fixed the issue. I'm fairly certain this clears out TeamCity's working directories, which forces TeamCity to grab a clean copy from the repo. This seems to have resolved the issue.